# Java sockets server, on a clustered server

Tags: java, sockets, server

I've a question which may seem strange, but I'm working in a environment which has very restricted options.
Basically, I've a job which runs on a *SAP Netweaver server*, which is clustered.
This job runs socket server code, which allows an ancient system to communicate with it.
My question is this: 
Depending on which side of the cluster the job runs on (and I can't influence this), the sock server will either run on a .127 IP or a .129 IP. 
Since the connecting system needs a fixed IP to connect to, It gives me a problem.
So, can I open the socket on the .127 IP each time, regardless of which of the two IP the Job happens to be running on, or does it have to be opened on the same IP that the code is actually running on ?

Comment: I'd guess you need some kind of load balancer in front of your service. It listens on a fixed IP address and forwards requests to the correct backend IP.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can't influence the server, you can introduce a component between the ancient system and the cluster that will redirect the request to one of the IPs in the cluster (.127 / .129 in your example).

```
                                                      |-> [IP .127]
[ancient system] --> [load balancing/proxy component] |
                                                      |-> [IP .129]
```

An actual implementation can vary, basically it boils down to hardware based solution or software based solution.

**Hardware**

Some network equipment, like load balancers provide this feature, so talk to your network department about this, they'll provide a couple of options.

**Software**

You can install solutions like "ha-proxy" that will solve this at the level of software